# How to retrieve multiple tags of same name in xml under single common tag in xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<body>
   <sec id="1.1">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>I am here</p>
      <p>I live here</p>
   </sec>
</body>
```

Now I have this xslt.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="body/sec">
   <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

And I want output as

```
Hello
I am here.
```

But it is showing as

```
Hello
```

It is reading only first (`<p>`) tag and gives in output. But i want both tags to be read and gives the output. What should I write in my xslt in order to get values of similar multiple tags(`<p>`) under common tag(`<sec>`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your XSLT like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="body/sec/p">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```